# Dynamic / autopopulating rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem I am trying to solve.

Looking at the attached image, you see Function 1, which has 5 names underneath.
Is it possible (with excel) to have the names auto-populate, based on data from a separate sheet?
So reading which individuals belong to Function 1, and bring all of those names below?

I can use a vlookup, but I would need to manually drag the formula up/down to update the fields.
Ideally I would like the list of names to auto-adjust based on the actual data (i.e. list of employees). So if an employee is deleted from the supporting sheet, the tab

It needs to be run for up to 50 different business units etc (see 2nd image).

So basically pivot-table type functionality, without a pivot-table.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Nicolas

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have Office 365 look into FILTER function.

Comment: There needs to be more information on the other table that you are collecting the data from. A screenshot would be helpful. Also you need to define what the inputs would be - what is used to create the list?

Comment: @markfitzpatrick thanks for the reply! it would be employee data table: 

ID; Function 1; Function 2; Function 3; Job Title; Surname; Name; . . . etc

So looking at my original post, "Written Off" would be Function 1 - so I want an autopopulating list of surname for whomever is in that function. Or it could be of a specific Function 2 - but this should not (in my mind) change the basic logic? 

Does this help clarify?